# Powershell Where-Object Not Filtering Expanded Property

Tags: powershell, exchange, exchange-2016

I am trying to get a list of all email addresses that we have registered in our on-prem Exchange but I want to exclude all of the X400 type addresses.  I have tried all of the following commands:

```
Get-Recipient | select name,recipienttype -expand emailaddresses | select name,recipienttype,prefix,addressstring,isprimaryaddress | where -property prefix -eq 'SMTP'
Get-Recipient | select name,recipienttype -expand emailaddresses | select name,recipienttype,prefix,addressstring,isprimaryaddress | where {$_.prefix -eq 'SMTP'}
Get-Recipient | select name,recipienttype -expand emailaddresses | select name,recipienttype,prefix,addressstring,isprimaryaddress | where-object {$_.prefix -eq 'SMTP'}
Get-Recipient | select name,recipienttype -expand emailaddresses | where-object {$_.prefix -eq 'SMTP'} | select name,recipienttype,prefix,addressstring,isprimaryaddress
Get-Recipient | select name,recipienttype -expand emailaddresses | where-object -property Prefix -eq 'SMTP' | select name,recipienttype,prefix,addressstring,isprimaryaddress
```

If I exclude the where-object, it returns everything fine.  What am I missing?  I am using the Exchange Management Shell running Powershell 5.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing that the `Prefix` property is not a string. You could call the ToString method but as there is `PrefixString` available it would be simpler to use that.

```
Get-Recipient | select name,recipienttype -expand emailaddresses | select name,recipienttype,prefixstring,addressstring,isprimaryaddress | ? { $_.PrefixString -eq "smtp" }
```

Comment: This works perfectly, thanks!  Out of curiosity, what is the Prefix property if not a string?

Comment: Its `Microsoft.Exchange.Data.SmtpProxyAddressPrefix`. You can pipe objects to `Get-Member` if you're unsure.

Answer (score -1):

You can try the following command to list all SMTP email addresses.

```
Get-Recipient | Select Name -ExpandProperty EmailAddresses | Select Name,  SmtpAddress
```

If you want to export the output with a csv file.

```
Get-Recipient | Select Name -ExpandProperty EmailAddresses | Select Name, SmtpAddress | Export-csv c:\mailAddress.csv
```

Comment: Thanks but this doesn't really address my question which is how to properly filter out the X400 addresses from the results.